# Signal: Ratchet & Message History

Tags: encryption

Hi folks– new to cryptography. My understanding of the double ratchet algorithm (or even just any ratchet algorithm) is that it uses all of the previous state (in Signal's case, all the previous messages in that thread) to compute the next ephemeral key. Does this mean that message history must be saved in order for